# Does the Windows Certification Authority support CMC Requests with CRMF Request Body?

Tags: windows-server-2008-r2, ad-certificate-services

I have a program that generates [CMC](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc2797)
certificate requests with a
[CRMF Request Body](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc2797#section-3.3.2). When I
submit this request to a certification authority running on Windows
Server 2008 R2 Enterprise it always fails with the error

> ASN1 corrupted data. 0x80093103 (ASN: 259)

Unfortunately that error doesn't tell me what is wrong with the request.

According to Microsoft's documentation for the Windows Client Certificate
Enrollment Protocol the
[CMC Request Format](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc249738.aspx)
supports the `CertReqMsg` field which is used for CRMF requests.

I have tried a CMC request with a
[PKCS10 Request Body](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc2797#section-3.3.1) and
it was processed and a certificate was issued.

I also checked the format of the requests and compared it to an
[example request](https://access.redhat.com/site/documentation/en-US/Red_Hat_Certificate_System_Common_Criteria_Certification/8.1/html/Command-Line_Tools_Guide/output-cmcrequest.html)
with an ASN.1 decoder and the format seems to be correct. The example request is
also rejected by the CA with the same error.

So I was wondering if CMC requests with a CRMF request body are actually
supported or are there any special requirements for the request needed by the
certification authority that are normally optional in the
specification?